# Remove link to something that is not a folder in the Finder sidebar

Tags: snow-leopard, finder

Somehow I managed to have a link to a document in my Finder sidebar (Mac OS X Snow Leopard, 10.6). It does show up under my “Places” category on the left. I can move it around and it sticks where I put it, but I can’t remove it from the sidebar.

If I perform a right click on it, the only option it gives me is “Open Sidebar Preferences...”, while that menu on a folder also gives me the option to remove it from the sidebar. I can not simply pull it away using drag and drop. It can not be focused, so I can’t even hit Cmd+Backspace or Fn+Backspace (for Del).

Any ideas? I want to remove it from the Sidebar and I guess I need to tweak some properties file. What to do?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This behavior got [changed with the 10.6.7 update](http://tidbits.com/article/12183?rss) - apparently to avoid accidental deletion from the sidebar. Now the behavior is consistent with removing system icons from the menubar.

Hold the <kbd>⌘</kbd>-key while dragging the icon away from the sidebar to remove it.